# Netlogo: how to register the tick-advance counter as a variable?

Tags: variables, counter, netlogo

I would like to register the tick-advance counter as a variable and use it for calculation in mathematical formulas, for example, (A + B) * tickadvance. However, Netlogo seems to be unable to register the tick-advance counter as a variable. Below is a sample syntax where "Expected reporter" error has been issued. This does not go well.

```
globals [tickadvance example-f]
;Omission;
set tickadvance (tick-advance 0.001) ;"Expected reporter" is occurring with this syntax.
set example-f ((A + B) * tickadvance)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it the other way around.  In `setup` you can include `set tickadvance 0.001`, and then in your code, you can call `tick-advance tickadvance`.

Alternatively, if you really just want `ticks`, see the answer of @JensB.

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply wanting the value of the counter, then you just need `ticks` (that is, `tick` is the command to advance the counter, and `ticks` reports the current value of the counter, note the **s** at the end)